# php mysql page not display data from mysql table row

Tags: php, mysql

When I run this I am getting no errors and no data back. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include 'connnectionmsql.php';

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    //Query

    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT carid, carname FROM Cars WHERE carid = '1578'"); 

    $sql->execute() ;

?>
<div id="contents">
    <header>
        <div id="top">
            <div class="h2">
                <?php while( $row = $sql->fetch()) : ?>
                <h1><span><?php echo $row['carname']; ?></span>
                <?php endwhile ?>
```

Comment: *"No errors"*.  - I see no error handling whatsoever.

Comment: A lot of problems can be detected and resolved by [enabling exceptions in `mysqli`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) so mistakes aren't easily ignored.

Comment: is there data in the table?

Comment: this code is incomplete. So.... how are you running this off of? as `file:///`? on a hosted site? local?

Comment: yes there is data in the table hosted on linux server vps

Comment: If the carid column is numeric remove the single quotes around it in your query.

Comment: also php errors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: add some text around see what comes back

Comment: text is coming back like it's having issue pulling the results

Comment: No errors? try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` to the top

Comment: added that line nothing

Comment: What does the query return using phpAdmin (or similar)?

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0005 seconds.)  1578 Nissan

Comment: If you're getting 0 rows then either your query is wrong or your table is empty (which you already said is not the case). @Dave above had a good suggestion. Is `carid` a numeric field? You have it in quotes.

Comment: Its int(11) for field name carid

Comment: $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT carid, carname FROM Cars WHERE caridid = 1578");  still nothing

Comment: You haven't bound the results to anything.  "Fetch results from a prepared statement into the bound variables".  See [bind_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)